# ODE modelling of mixing problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

A tank contains 2140 L of pure water. A solution that contains 0.01
kg of sugar per liter enters the tank at the rate 2 L/min, and is thoroughly mixed into it. The new solution drains out of the tank at the same rate. Find an equation with which you can find the amount of sugar in the tank at any given time.

I tried integrating dA/dt= 2*0.01 - A/1070 but it isn't giving me the right answer.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say you tried integrating the equation above, what exactly do you mean?  Integrating with respect to $t$?

Comment: With respect to A, it gave me 0.02A-0.00046A^2 @TMGallagher

Comment: Integration with respect to $A$ is not so clearly understood for this differential equation since $\frac{dA}{dt}$ is present.  As a hint, you should recognize that the DE you've constructed is first order and linear.

Comment: Is the initial dA/dt equation that I chose to integrate correct? If so, I guess I'm stuck at the integration part @TMGallagher

Comment: Yes, the ODE is correct. Now apply the method of separation of variables.

Comment: I got it now thank you! @LutzL